# Some application sets alarm loudness to zero

Tags: alarm

For some reason some application sets the alarm loudness over night to zero.
How do I find out which application is to blame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look for applications that do require this permission: `android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS`

Then uninstall it and set the alarm a short while after that. If everything is back to normal you have found the application in question.